# Replacing Controller and function name with attribute in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, url-title, codeigniter, .htaccess, routing

in htaccess or route.php where from you want you can give answer for this issue.

I Need some thing like this.if i have url :

```
http://tageto.pnf-sites.info/developer/headcategory_controller/head_category/Agriculture
```

than it must be replaced into

```
http://tageto.pnf-sites.info/developer/Agriculture
```

and if i have url like this

```
http://tageto.pnf-sites.info/developer/headcategory_controller/sub_category/Rice
```

than it must be replaced into

```
http://tageto.pnf-sites.info/developer/Rice
```

and if i have url like this

```
http://tageto.pnf-sites.info/developer/products/view_product/nokia-internet-stick-cs-17-hsdpa-144mbps-logo-nokia-black-1
```

than it must be replaced into

```
http://tageto.pnf-sites.info/developer/nokia-internet-stick-cs-17-hsdpa-144mbps-logo-nokia-black-1
```

Can anybody solve my this issue? Please reply rapidly.

.htaccess

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

RewriteEngine On

```
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  #  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 

To remove index.php i need all i mentioned above for url so that url becomes canonical.

Answer (score 2):

[Template Routes](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/template-routes)

> Control your URLs by remapping URI routes to a specific template, using CodeIgniter-style routing rules.

```
$config['template_routes'] = array(
    'blog/:category' => 'site/blog-category',
    'blog/:year/:pagination' => 'site/blog-yearly-archive',
    'blog/:any' => 'site/blog-single',
);
```

Comment: Sir i already using it [$route['headcategory/(:any)'] = 'headcategory_controller/headcategory/$1';
$route['subcategory/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'headcategory_controller/subcategory/$1/$2';] . But i want to remove [subcategory] and [headcategory] before it

Comment: i try it but user controller not working. show error is 404 url not found